# sed replace string in a first line

Tags: string, replace, sed

How can I replace a string but only in the first line of the file using the program "sed"?

The commands `s/test/blah/1` and `1s/test/blah/` don't seem to work. Is there another way?

Comment: what about `1s/test/blah/` "does not work"?

Answer (score 36):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '1!b;s/test/blah/' file
```

will only substitute the first `test` for `blah` on the first line only.

Or if you just want to *change* the first line:

```
sed -i '1c\replacement' file
```

Comment: @lzap "1!b" = if `not` on line `1` then `b`ranch to end of script

Comment: Using `b` can make other replacements being ignored, for example when using multiple `-e` options.

Comment: This is good but in only works for the first match in the first line. What if the string you want to replace is found more than once in the first line and you need to replace all of them? In that case, this solution doesn't work.

Comment: @CarolinaCárdenas i used this: sed -i '1s/test/blah/g' file

Answer (score 4):

This will do it:

```
sed -i '1s/^.*$/Newline/' textfile.txt
```

Failing that just make sure the match is unique to line one only:

```
sed -i 's/this is line one and its unique/Changed line one to this string/' filename.txt
```

The `-i` option writes the change to the file instead of just displaying the output to stdout.

EDIT:

To replace the whole line by matching the common string would be:

```
sed -i 's/^.*COMMONSTRING$/Newline/'
```

Where `^` matches the start of the line, `$` matches the end of the line and `.*` matches everything upto `COMMONSTRING`

Comment: the line is different everytime with one common string at the end, but you gave me an idea how to solve this, thanks! ;)

Answer (score 2):

this replaces all matches, not just the first match, only in the first line of course:

```
 sed -i '1s/test/blah/g' file
```

**the /g did the trick** to replace more than one matches, if any exists.